# PHP not saving online file locally

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP on localhost to save the contents of an online file to my computer.

```
$url='https://mydomain.online/hello.txt';
echo file_get_contents($url).'<br />'; // to verify I got it
$myfile = 'hello.txt';
file_put_contents($myfile, file_get_contents($url));
```

It seems to take longer than it should, then does not return anything on line 2. It creates an empty hello.txt file on my computer.

If I paste the url into my browser the text displays correctly.

I'm sure I've done this before, but I can't get it to work today. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mydomain.online` might be blocking bots (by user agent and other measures). Consider using cURL or Guzzle to get better error handling on rejected HTTP calls.

Comment: do not use `file_get_contents()` for network access. Use `cUrl`, `Guzzle` instead. HTTP transport can be disabled for `file_get_contents()` and you will be doomed then

Comment: Also, instead of trying to download the file twice assign the result of `file_get_contents()` to a variable and use that for subsequent operations instead.

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if `file_get_contents()` is getting an error.

Comment: Thank you Marcin Orlowski. I haven't used Guzzle before, but it worked perfectly!